# How to configure Android Studio to build projects offline?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I downloaded Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.6 (as it comes with built in SDK Tools, SDK Platform Tools, SDK Build Tools,
Android 4.4W and Android Support Repository) to start android program development on CentOS7 and had Open JDK 1.8.0.131.

I created new simple  hello world kind of project, myapplication.

I would like to build the application in offline mode:

Referred:

a) [android studio 3.1.4 offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215947/android-studio-3-1-4-offline-mode/52216530#52216530)

b) [How to setup Android Studio to work completely offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158034/how-to-setup-android-studio-to-work-completely-offline)

c) [How to setup Android Studio to work completely offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158034/how-to-setup-android-studio-to-work-completely-offline/18288590#18288590)

d) [Does Android studio need internet connection to build project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746087/does-android-studio-need-internet-connection-to-build-project/24019199#24019199)

e) [setting gradle on offline mode in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511687/setting-gradle-on-offline-mode-in-android-studio/50511790#50511790)

But they are not leading to any definite solution.

I tried to solve the issue in the following ways:

a) downloaded gradle-1.12-all.zip and placed in folder, /opt/gradle/

b) edited gradle-wrapper.properties from 
`distributionUrl=http\:///services.gradle.org.distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip` to

```
distributionUrl=file:///opt/gradle/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

c) downloaded gradle-0.12.2.jar, gradle-0.12.2.pom and placed in folder, /opt/android-studio/lib/

While compiling, getting exception: **"No cached version com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2" available for offline mode**!

d) Also, put gradle-0.12.2.jar, gradle-0.12.2.pom and placed project lib folder and found that build.gradle has

```
dependencies{
    compile fileTree(dir:'libs', include: [*.jar])
}
```

Still, the exception: **"No cached version com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2" available for offline mode** persists!

I doubt I am placing the the gradle-0.12.2.jar, gradle-0.12.2.pom in wrong path!

Please guide me in building application in offline mode!

(ps: pardon me for raising the well known issue which is discussed many a times! I am optimistic as the un-available gradle-0.12.2 can be made available to the system!)

Comment: Why are you installing 0.8.6??

Comment: Newer versions has stdc++ issue! tried with android studion3.3 canary!

Comment: What if you try with the stable version?

Comment: Downloaded and unzipped latest stable version android-studio-ide-173.4907809-linux.zip and got "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool"